# Heroku H10 error coed with Error 503, can someone give me some insight?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Cant deploy web app to heroku, the error codes are H10 and Error 503. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Ive look up abit on this, I dont use a database. Thought deleting the db folder would do something. Did  heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate and heroku restart after and it didnt seem to do anything.

```
2019-04-15T21:34:25.020968+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.020971+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.020987+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.020989+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.020992+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.020993+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.020995+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:235:in `<class:Blob>'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.020996+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `<main>'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.020998+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021001+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021003+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021019+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021021+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021027+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021030+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021031+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021032+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021033+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021036+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021037+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021038+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021040+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021042+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021045+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021049+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021051+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021054+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021056+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:85:in `depend_on'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021058+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021060+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021062+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021065+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021084+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021085+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021086+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021089+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021091+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021109+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021111+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021113+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021116+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021133+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021135+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021137+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021138+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021141+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021142+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021144+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021149+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021150+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021152+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021155+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021157+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021159+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021161+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021163+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021181+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021182+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021183+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021186+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021187+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021189+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021191+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021193+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021195+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `new'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021197+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `<main>'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021200+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021202+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021204+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021206+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021208+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021211+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021228+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021229+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021230+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021233+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021234+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021236+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021237+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021239+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021242+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021244+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021246+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021262+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021264+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021265+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021268+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021269+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021287+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021289+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021291+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021294+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.021312+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2019-04-15T21:34:25.023397+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2019-04-15T21:34:25.023398+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2019-04-15T21:35:45.696351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/beta/wp-admin/" host=www.bradgrad.graphics request_id=962814b5-d073-4d2b-9916-db9882513153 fwd="39.104.203.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-04-15T21:39:14.473791+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.bradgrad.graphics request_id=da637bcd-a0fb-453d-9b15-ce16544a55ea fwd="174.62.232.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-04-15T21:52:25.375916+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.bradgrad.graphics request_id=31deb905-fb29-4804-974f-bb5a7fa7501c fwd="174.62.232.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Looking to deploy the website I have it works locally, I know its not good practice to use ruby on rails without databases, but I figured a bare bones app is better to start out with and uploading a more complex on later is good.

Comment: If you run `rails s production` locally you'll have more insight about why your app won't startup in prod

Comment: Thanks, gonna try that.